# Trigger in postgres not raising exception

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a trigger working in postgres, it allows a view to become updateable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION actualizaIDConductor() RETURNS 
TRIGGER AS '
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE ''Working'';      

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bool
        FROM Infotrenes
        WHERE cod_empleado = OLD.cod_empleado;

        RAISE NOTICE ''bool = %'', bool;      

        --The id belongs to the view
        IF (bool > 0) THEN
            UPDATE ...; --This works fine
        ELSE
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''ERROR: ...'';
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The "problem" comes when I want to update a row that doesn't belong to the view. Instead of printing my "ERROR:..." message it just displays UPDATE 0. It doesn't even display the "Working" notice.

Is this some sort of the manager optimization or am I doing something wrong? Can I somehow print the message?

Comment: where is `bool` declared? I can't find it.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: What you display is *not* a trigger but is a *trigger function*. It doesn't do anything by itself. (It's also invalid.) [Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625409/need-assistance-with-a-postgres-trigger-and-function/15626828#15626828)You need to show all the necessary information including trigger and view definition and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

This code should not to work - there are undeclared variable bool (secondary - it's wrong name due same named data type). So this code should not to work ever, and should not to raise a notice 'working'.